# ¿De dónde proviene la palabra "résped"?

Tags: etimología, palabras-raras, animales

La palabra résped viene recogida en el  Diccionario de la lengua española actual como:

> 1. m. Lengua de la culebra o de la víbora.
>
> 2. m. Intención malévola en las palabras.

sin ninguna indicación etimológica.

Parece que la palabra fue incorporada al DLE en 1947.

¿Cuál es su etimología?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algo se explica en el diccionario etimológico de Corominas:

- Se parte de la palabra *[híspido](https://dle.rae.es/h%C3%ADspido)*, del latín *hispĭdus*, sinónima de *hirsuto*, con el significado de "cubierto de pelo disperso y duro, o de púas y espinas", con poco arraigo en el idioma.
- Más arraigo dice que tiene *[ríspido](https://dle.rae.es/r%C3%ADspido)*, variante de la anterior usando el prefijo *re-*, y con el significado de "áspero, violento, intratable". Esta y la anterior se recogen desde 1817.
- Variante de esta última es *[rispo](https://dle.rae.es/rispo)*, que en el Bajo Aragón se usaba para denominar al "hombre de mal genio".
- Finalmente aclara que de un cruce entre *rispo* y *[guizque](https://dle.rae.es/guizque)* o *vizque* (en el sentido de "lengua de culebra", aunque el DLE recoge más bien el sentido de "aguijón") surgió *[respe](https://dle.rae.es/respe)*, sinónima de *[resped](https://dle.rae.es/r%C3%A9sped)* en su significado de "lengua de la culebra", y además con el significado de "aguijón de la abeja o la avispa", y además las variantes regionales *rezpe* y *resque*. *Respe* figura en el DLE desde 1925. Indica además las variantes *réspidi* y *rézpede* por el influjo de *císpid*, y otras.

Answer (score 3):

*Respe / résped(e) / rézped(e)* es un regionalismo [montañés](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A1ntabro_(ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica)). Su origen es incierto, posiblemente onomatopéyico, pero Baraibar sugiere que viene del latín:

> **Réspidi.** Puede ser voz onomatopéyica como su sinónimo cispe, del silbido especial de la serpiente irritada o apercibida para la deíensa; o de *réspice* imperativo del verbo latino: *respicére*: mirar atrás. (F. Baraibar). También *rézpede: griju de culiebra*.

- [Estudio Del Dialecto Popular Montañés Fonética, Etimologías Y Glosario De Voces](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/71527851.pdf) (1922)
- [Anales del Instituto de Lingüística](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Anales_del_Instituto_de_Ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica/cLfeutYtyRQC?gbpv=1&bsq=r%C3%A9spidi) (Vol.3) (1945)

Corominas y otros listan varias ["contaminaciones"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/contamination) que pueden haber influenciado la forma '-ede' etc:

[image]

- *Diccionario Crítico Etimológico Castellano e Hispánico* (1984)

> La palabra "réspidi" o "respe" tiene dos significaciones en montañés: se toma para designar la lengua de la culebra, llamada también "grijo", y denota, además, malas intenciones o carácter agrio de una persona.
>
> Como universalmente suele trasladarse el nombre *culebra* para designar la envidia y perversidad de alguno (y lo prueba en la Montaña el apodo "culiebra"
> que se da a mujeres astutas), me inclino a pensar que ha habido una fusión de *áspid*, muy usado en el Siglo de Oro, y *réspice*, palabra que significa en castellano *contestación agria o reprensión seca y fuerte*. Si solamente tuviese el término montañés el segundo de los significados expuestos, diríamos que su origen estaba, únicamente, en *réspice*; pero, puesto que significa también (y creo que ésta es su acepción más propia) la lengua de las culebras, pienso que no se puede prescindir de *áspid* al buscar su etimología.
>
> Por consiguiente, juzgo que el pueblo, mezclando las dos palabras castellanas *áspid* y *réspice*, ha formado el término montañés que incluye las acepciones de una y otra.

- [Altamira - Revista del Centro de Estudios Montañeses](https://centrodeestudiosmontaneses.com/wp-content/uploads/DOC_CEM/HEMEROTECA/ALTAMIRA/Altamira1947.pdf) (1947) (p.144 *Etimología popular*)

---

**Notas:**

La polisemia histórica entre el aguijón y la *lengua* de una culebra se daba en inglés también:

> "Sting ... Applied also to the fang or venom-tooth (and erroneously to the forked tongue) of a poisonous serpent."
>
> - [Oxford English Dictionary, 2nd ed.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aguij%C3%B3n#cite_ref-5)